# XSL stylesheet differences

Tags: html, css, xml

I am trying to understand the difference between these two links:

The first one uses XSLT to style the xml data file, but I can't see the "stylesheet" word writen anywhere.

> http://www.w3schools.com/xml/tryxslt.asp?xmlfile=simple&xsltfile=simple

This one it can be seen that is clearly a xsl stylesheet file, (xsl:stylesheet version="1.0").

> http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/tryxslt.asp?xmlfile=cdcatalog&xsltfile=cdcatalog

They both export and style a XML file as an HTML+CSS file. So what is the main difference between them ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first one uses the "simplified stylesheet" syntax. This was designed to reduce the amount of boilerplate text that's needed in a very simple stylesheet (allowing "Hello world" to be written in one or two lines rather than ten), but it's very rarely used in practice, because very few people ever write "Hello world" stylesheets in anger.